# Extract values from more than one attribute value from JSON using Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column like this in GBQ.

```
[{rank_start: 1, rank_end: 1, prize: {unit_type: 'UNIT_TYPE1', units: 50, unit_currency: 'UNIT_CURRENCY1'}}, {rank_start: 2, rank_end: 50, prize: {unit_type: 'UNIT_TYPE2', units: 20, unit_currency: 'UNIT_CURRENCY2'}}, {rank_start: 51, rank_end: 100, prize: {unit_type: 'UNIT_TYPE3', units: 10, unit_currency: 'UNIT_CURRENCY3'}}, {rank_start: 101, rank_end: 500, prize: {unit_type: 'UNIT_TYPE4', units: 5, unit_currency: 'UNIT_CURRENCY4'}}]
```

I want to extract values like **rank_start, rank_end, unit_type, units, unit_currency** for each rank range in GBQ.

I know how to do this if we have just one rank range i.e using **JSON_EXTRACT() or JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR()**...I would have completed it.

But the thing is here we have more than attribute value in the JSON.

Can anybody help how can we do this in GBQ ??

I have tried the crude way of the doing this i.e splitting with comma multiple times & then splitting with ':' and then replacing the ''' with '' and I am taking the OFFSET values at each split according to the need.

But this makes the code too clumsy with lot of REPLACE & SPLIT going on and inefficient.

I would like to see if there is anyway of do this in GBQ using JSON functions mentioned above ??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the arrays, and use JSON_EXTRACT. Depending on how you want to get the results, is the final step of the transformation. Here is an example of how you could do it:

```sql
-- Recreating your scenario

WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT ['{"rank_start": 1, "rank_end": 1, "prize": {"unit_type": "UNIT_TYPE1", "units": 50, "unit_currency": "UNIT_CURRENCY1"}}', '{"rank_start": 2, "rank_end": 50, "prize": {"unit_type": "UNIT_TYPE2", "units": 20, "unit_currency": "UNIT_CURRENCY2"}}', '{"rank_start": 51, "rank_end": 100, "prize": {"unit_type": "UNIT_TYPE3", "units": 10, "unit_currency": "UNIT_CURRENCY3"}}', '{"rank_start": 101, "rank_end": 500, "prize": {"unit_type": "UNIT_TYPE4", "units": 5, "unit_currency": "UNIT_CURRENCY4"}}'] as my_column
)

-- Extracting information

SELECT 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT(
    JSON_EXTRACT(myrank, "$['rank_start']"), '-',
    JSON_EXTRACT(myrank, "$['rank_end']"), '-',
    JSON_EXTRACT(myrank, "$['prize'].unit_type"), '-',
    JSON_EXTRACT(myrank, "$['prize'].units"), '-',
    JSON_EXTRACT(myrank, "$['prize'].unit_currency")))
   FROM UNNEST(my_table.my_column) as myrank ) as fields
FROM
  my_table
```

Here is an example of the ouput:

[image: Query output]

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#top_of_page) is BigQuery documentation to work with arrays.